# In setting TPs and SLs, how close from the current price and entry price can you get?

Tags: python, algorithmic-trading, trading, binance, binance-api-client

I can't seem to find official document stating this limit. I might have missed something from the docs.

I keep on getting this error every once in a while and I want to know how much I can tighten my TPs and SLs (Sadly I dont think i can test every difference through the API since prices are live and moving):

`BinanceAPIException: APIError(code=-2021): Order would immediately trigger.`

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you should take into consideration the spread :

"the spread is the gap between the bid and the ask prices of a security or asset, like a stock, bond, or commodity. This is known as a bid-ask spread."

[https://www.investopedia.com/terms/s/spread.asp#:~:text=Generally%2C%20the%20spread%20refers%20to,as%20a%20bid%2Dask%20spread](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/s/spread.asp#:%7E:text=Generally%2C%20the%20spread%20refers%20to,as%20a%20bid%2Dask%20spread).

so regarding the values you have to take it into consideration , example if you're spread is 2 pip , setting a sl with 2/3 pip will immediately trigger it ..